# error 1236 A slave with the same server_uuid/server_id as this slave has connected to the master

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, connection, binary-files

tengo esta circunstancia,
escribí una serie de scripts en node.js para realizar diferentes tareas,

enumero la lista para poder describirlos a detalle:

- retransmitir datos a un servidor.
- envio de sms
- sevidor websockets.

**- retransmitir datos a un servidor.**
este se conecta al blinlog de MYSQL, captura eventos de escritura en una DB especifica, ordena los datos y envía por curl a un servidor el cual me responde con status OK, si falla reintenta por 4 veces, si aun así falla guarda el dato en un archivo de texto plano, acumula sus registros por semana y los envía por correo al cliente para que lo procese de forma manual.

**- envio de sms**
este no cumple otra función que usar los datos del binlog ya capturados, observa datos que se han programado como eventos y al detectarlos envía SMS de alerta a los clientes que tengan dicha opción activada en su sistema.

**- sevidor websockets.**
este también usa el mismo binlog, para enviar actualizaciones automáticas a los clientes, conectados al servicio.

todos usan la única conexión al binlog, y para poder trabajar de forma eficiente se crearon subprocesos que realizan toda las tareas.

esta funcionado en servidor de pruebas.
y cuando lo desplegamos a los servidores de producción nos topamos con un detalle
solo se puede ejecutar en uno de ellos

y es un por la conexión al binlog, creo que solo admite 1 y nada mas.

el error era el siguiente:

```
error 1236 A slave with the same server_uuid/server_id as this slave has connected to the master
```

evidentemente omití, una configuración que enmarcare en mi respuesta.

Comment: significa que puedo responder mi pregunta?

Comment: Claro que si...

Comment: habrá algún problema con esto?
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

**Respuesta 15 de febrero de 2021**

revisado el tipo de error 1236 de mysql, **replicación de id de servidor**
y revisando la documentación de la dependencia que uso
**@rodrigogs/mysql-events** llegue a la conclusión que se puede asignar el id de servidor, en la instance del mismo, quedando **serverId: 2**
ya que el numero 1 es el master de donde cojo los binlog  como se muestra a continuación:

**extracto de configuración de etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**

```
server-id                   = 1
binlog_format               = row
log-bin-index               = bin-log.index
log_bin                     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
binlog_expire_logs_seconds  = 60
max_binlog_size             = 1M
binlog_do_db                = db_que_escucho
binlog-ignore-db            = test
binlog-ignore-db            = information_schema
binlog-ignore-db            = mysql
```

y obviamente las nuevas conexiones deben tener un id diferente. **serverId: 2**

```
const instance = new MySQLEvents(DBcon, {
        startAtEnd: true,
        serverId: 2,
        excludedSchemas: {
                mysql: true,
        }
})
```

esto resuelve mi pregunta y queda para algún alma desventurada que la pueda usar.